# Calling a scala function with a request from another function

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a scala function that looks like:

```
   def myFunction(x: Option[String]) = Action { request =>
           ...
           ...
           ...
   }
```

I want to call this function from another scala function. How can this be done? What should request match to?

Action is defined in `play.api.mvc._`

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.html

Typically `myFunction` is called through a post command as `myFunction` has some commands to save the info coming through request into a DB. However, I need those commands to be executed from a call inside another scala function so I was wondering how to call `myFunction` from the other scala function (both functions are in the same application). Out of that, I need no other thing. We could make the assumption that both functions are within the same package.

Comment: where is `Action` defined? some library?

Comment: What is the use case for this? Are you looking to retrieve the `Result` object of the `Action` without needing an actual request? Are you trying to call it for some side effect? Are you trying to set up a logging or authentication layer around your action? Those all have different answers.

Comment: I was trying to use that function to avoid creating another one with the commands that sent information to the database. Because of time I had to copy the needed commands and run them in another function.

Answer (score 0):

Is the function part of a class? You can create an instance of class and call myFunction. Or you can use wSClient to form a request.